# Does there need to be a comma between 'that' and 'on'?

Tags: commas

> The woman states that on 3/23/20, her husband pushed her.

Does there need to be a comma between 'that' and 'on'?

Comment: If you put the comma after "20", yes.  (Look up "parenthetical expression".)

Comment: I'd not use a comma at all here. But using one before and after the temporal phrase (on 3/23/20) would be acceptable too.